# Erro ao listar registro da tabela usando PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Pessoa, estou tentando listar os registros da tabela da base de dados, mas não estou conseguindo, estou obtendo o seguinte erro: *Undefined index: name in...* *Undefined index: email in...*
Com todos os campos está acontecendo isso, e acredito que isso esteja acontecendo pelo fato de eu estar usando o *fetchAll() do PDO*, pois quando uso apenas o *fetch()*, o script roda normalmente, porém, exibe apenas um registro, conto com vocês para me auxiliar nisso...

**Source:**

```
<?php

include_once 'header.php';
require_once 'bitch.php'; //Connection with database
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 push-m3">
       <h3>Clients</h3>
        <table class="striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>Nome:</th>
                    <th>Sobrenome:</th>
                    <th>Email:</th>
                    <th>Idade:</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM crud";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                        $result->execute();
                        if($result->rowCount() > 0):
                            $row = $result->fetchAll();
                            //print_r($row);
                    ?>
                    <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['sobrenome']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['idade']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn-floating orange"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></td>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
                <a href="adicionar.php" class="btn">ADICIONAR</a>
    </div>
</div>



<?php

include_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `fetch` retorna um resultado, o método `fetchAll` retorna todos. Portanto você deve iterar sobre o resultado de `fetchAll`:

```php
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM crud";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result->execute();
if($result->rowCount() > 0):
  $rows = $result->fetchAll();
  foreach($rows as $row):
?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['sobrenome']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['idade']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn-floating orange"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></td>
                  </tr>
<?php
  endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo. Entretanto, ainda há um erro, você pode me ajudar? É que os registros estão sendo exibidos sem quebra de linha, todos eles estão em uma única linha

Comment: Verdade, está faltando inserir as linhas da tabela. As linhas da tabela são representadas pela tag `<tr>`. Editei a resposta com a tr.

Comment: Pronto, agora deu certo, muito obrigado por tudo!

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.